# Error building SqlSession

Tags: mybatis

I'm learning how to use Mybatis and I'm doing the tutorial on tutorialpoint.com. [the tutorial link][1] but I am getting the following error

This is my configuration file

```
    <configuration>

       <environments default = "development">
          <environment id = "development">
             <transactionManager type = "JDBC"/> 

             <dataSource type = "POOLED">
                <property name = "driver" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
                <property name = "url" value =     "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/details"/>
                <property name = "username" value = "root"/>
                <property name = "password" value = "f8802700@"/>
             </dataSource>   

          </environment>
       </environments>

   <mappers>
      <mapper resource = "MyBatisPractice/Student.xml"/>
   </mappers>

</configuration>
```

and this is my mapper file

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"   "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace = "Student">

   <insert id = "insert" parameterType = "Student">
      INSERT INTO STUDENT (NAME, BRANCH, PERCENTAGE, PHONE, EMAIL ) VALUES (#{name}, #{branch}, #{percentage}, #{phone}, #{email});

       <selectKey keyProperty = "id" resultType = "int" order = "AFTER">
          select last_insert_id() as id
      </selectKey>   

   </insert>

</mapper>
```

I followed exactly what the tutorial shows, but I'm getting and error building SqlSession. The first part of the error message

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
>
> #### Error building SqlSession.
>
> #### The error may exist in SQL Mapper Configuration
>
> #### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber:
>
> 1; columnNumber: 16; Document root element "configuration", must match
>   DOCTYPE root "null".  at
>   org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:8)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:32)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:15)
>     at MybatisInsert.main(MybatisInsert.java:18)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>   Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating
>   document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber:
>   1; columnNumber: 16; Document root element "configuration", must match
>   DOCTYPE root "null".  at
>   org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.createDocument(XPathParser.java:212)
>     at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.(XPathParser.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.(XMLConfigBuilder.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:28)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1;
>   columnNumber: 16; Document root element "configuration", must match
>   DOCTYPE root "null".  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1599)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1877)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:742)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1358)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1295)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3129)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.createDocument(XPathParser.java:210)
>     ... 10 more

Any suggestion to help me fix this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. The configuration file the tutorial has is missing DTD validation check. It works after I added the validation check.

```
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Confi 3.0//EN" "http://www.mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

<configuration>

   <environments default = "development">
      <environment id = "development">
         <transactionManager type = "JDBC"/> 

         <dataSource type = "POOLED">
            <property name = "driver" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/details"/>
            <property name = "username" value = "root"/>
            <property name = "password" value = "f8802700@"/>
         </dataSource>   

      </environment>
   </environments>

   <mappers>
      <mapper resource = "Student.xml"/>
   </mappers>

</configuration>
```